# Can anyone please tell me why is it showing "runtime error"?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to implement hash table, but I'm getting a runtime error in the *for* loop of *createHashTable()* function. Can anyone please tell me why is it showing this "runtime error"? Is it StackOverflow error?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define LOAD_FACTOR 20

struct ListNode{
    int data;
    struct ListNode *next;
};

struct HashTableNode{
    int bCount; // number of elements in the block
    struct ListNode *next;
};

struct HashTable{
    int tSize;  // table size
    int count;  // total number of elements in the table
    struct HashTableNode **hashTableNodeArray;
};

int hashFunction(struct HashTable *h, int data){
   return data % h->tSize;
}

struct HashTable * createHashTable(int numberOfElements){
   struct HashTable *h = new HashTable;
   h->count = 0;
   h->tSize = numberOfElements / LOAD_FACTOR;
   h->hashTableNodeArray = new HashTableNode *[h->tSize];
       for(int i = 0; i < h->tSize; ++i){
       // this is where it is showing runtime error
       h->hashTableNodeArray[i]->bCount = 0;
       h->hashTableNodeArray[i]->next = nullptr;
   }
   return h;
}

void deleteHashTable(struct HashTable *h){
   struct ListNode *node, *tmp;
   for(int i = 0; i < h->tSize; ++i){
       node = h->hashTableNodeArray[i]->next;
       while(node != nullptr){
           tmp = node;
           node = node->next;
           delete tmp;
       }
   }
   delete[] h->hashTableNodeArray;
   delete h;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
   struct HashTable *h = createHashTable(220);
   deleteHashTable(h);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post more information about the runtime error.

Comment: Probably because you're using a pointer in a way you're not supposed to, leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Use a debugger to find out *where* the crash happens.

Comment: Dunno.  What did you find out when you debugged it?

Comment: I like the c++11 tag on this question.

Comment: In case you're wondering, I've deleted the `c` tag because this is definitely not C --- `<iostream>`, `using namespace std;`, `new` and `delete` are not C (these are the most obvious; there might be other issues).

Comment: Why not use `std::unordered_map`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
h->hashTableNodeArray = new HashTableNode *[h->tSize];
```

This allocates an array of pointers, but not the actual hashtablenodes. In the following loop you try to write to them which is undefined behaviour.

You are missing in your loop:

```
h->hashTableNodeArray[i] = new HashTableNode;
```

Comment: How could I missed that!!! Feeling so dumb!!! errr!!!
Thank you so much for pointing that out. :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
h->hashTableNodeArray = new HashTableNode *[h->tSize];
for(int i = 0; i < h->tSize; ++i){
    // this is where it is showing runtime error
    h->hashTableNodeArray[i]->bCount = 0;
    h->hashTableNodeArray[i]->next = nullptr;
}
```

You allocate an array of pointers, but don't actually make the pointers point anywhere valid which means their values are *indeterminate* (and in reality seemingly random). You then proceed to dereference these uninitialized pointers, and write to memory using the pointers, without knowing *where* in memory you will write.

This leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and most likely your crash.

The solution? Either don't use pointers, or explicitly allocate the memory for the pointers. My recommendation is to stop using pointers altogether, create proper copy- and move-constructors, and use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.